# Error in joining 4 AVI files

Tags: avi

I have 4 avi files. Each file can be played properly in VLC player, Windows media player.
Video-Audio Codec type in each of this avi file is Xvid-Mpga.

I used below avi joiners: Quick AVI joiner, AVI join, BoilSoft Video Joiner(trial version), but all of them gave an error when i select the first part avi file saying :

"format of the part1.avi file cannot be recognized"..

What could be the problem.

How do i join these AVI files.

Any pointers will help.

Thanks.

-AD.

Comment: Even if VLC can play it there might be something broken in the avi file. Try fixing it, here are a few tips http://superuser.com/questions/4570/how-can-i-repair-a-broken-avi-file

Answer (score 1):

To join two files, they must have matching codecs, framerate and resolution. Try VirtualDub (you can follow [this tutorial](http://www.afterdawn.com/guides/archive/virtualdub_join_avi.cfm)) - if these prerequisites are met AND you have proper decoder installed, it should perform without problems.

Comment: Great call, VirtualDub is an indispensable "Swiss Army Knife" of AVI tools. It is also available as a portable app if you want to try it before a full install. http://portableapps.com/apps/music_video/virtualdub_portable.