# How to know what AVI files are "broken" in VLC?

Tags: ubuntu, vlc-media-player

I know how to repair "broken" AVI files in VLC: [How can I repair a broken AVI file?](https://superuser.com/questions/4570/how-can-i-repair-a-broken-avi-file/4602#4602)

But how can I detect that an AVI file is broken if I have thousands of AVI files, and I don't want to open them 1 by 1? I'm using Ubuntu, so are there any CLI methods to find them?

Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[DivFix++](http://sourceforge.net/projects/divfixpp/) does something similar that could solve your problem.

```
DivFix++ -w *
```

This just "fixes" the file regardless of their sanity and overwrites the originals with the fixed ones.

Answer (score 1):

This might be exactly what you are looking for: http://606u.dir.bg/avicheck/

Comment: I didn't downvote, but one link answers are discouraged here. Why not write about how to use that tool?

Comment: @slhck It's not a tool, it is a tutorial, describing how to detect avi corruption using ffmpeg.

Answer (score -1):

Typically when I was using Windows this error was present it was due to the file not being complete. I would assume the message with Ubuntu as well. I am currently using Ubuntu, but I do not have any .avi's to test with at the moment. I would check file sizes to make sure that it is the full .avi.

If you click "don't repair", it still should load and play but it'll most likely be incomplete.