# How can I check the integrity of an avi file and repair it automatically in Linux?

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, video-conversion

I have an avi file and tried to check it as suggested [here](https://superuser.com/questions/100288/how-can-i-check-the-integrity-of-a-video-file-avi-mpeg-mp4). But after a short while I just got a segmentation fault, without any other information!

How is it possible to fix/repair this avi file? Watching this file with `mplayer` just works fine, using it with `ffmpeg` or `kdenlive` is causing errors!

System: Ubuntu 13.10
Size file: 4.2 GB

Addition:

Here is part of the output(begin and end) when running the command (the FULL output is about 1 MB of text!)

```
ffmpeg -v error -i file.avi -f null -

Stream mapping:
  Stream #0.0 -> #0.0
  Stream #0.1 -> #0.1
Press ctrl-c to stop encoding
[dvvideo @ 0x21f39c0] AC EOB marker is absent pos=64
    Last message repeated 1 times
.....
(These kind of lines repeat over and over and over. I really do not see a point providing them all. There are no build information. Interlaced in the output are lines like:
frame=  124 fps=  0 q=0.0 size=      -0kB time=4.00 bitrate=  -0.0kbits/s
)
....
    Last message repeated 3 times
[dvvideo @ 0x1fad9c0] AC EOB marker is absent pos=69
[dvvideo @ 0x1fad9c0] AC EOB marker is absent pos=65
    Last message repeated 1 times
    [dvvideo @ 0x1fad9c0] AC EOB marker is absent pos=71
[dvvideo @ 0x1fad9c0] AC EOB marker is absent pos=75
[dvvideo @ 0x1fad9c0] AC EOB marker is absent pos=64
    Last message repeated 2 times
[dvvideo @ 0x1fad9c0] AC EOB marker is absent pos=70
[dvvideo @ 0x1fad9c0] AC EOB marker is absent pos=71
[dvvideo @ 0x1fad9c0] AC EOB marker is absent pos=67
[dvvideo @ 0x1fad9c0] AC EOB marker is absent pos=65
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Comment: What's wrong with the avi file? Why don't you show the actual errors? Can you provide a small sample file that will allow us to attempt to duplicate whever issue you are experiencing? Your `ffmpeg` command and the complete console output are important information.

Comment: As mentioned in the question, I got a `segmentation fault`, without any other message output. Maybe I can enable some debugging for `ffmpeg`? If so, how?

Comment: I have updated the question with some of the output ffmpeg` created. If people want to have a sample: How to create this sample?

Comment: Yes, I do not think this is possible. Its about 1 Megabyte! If you give your email address, I can email you the complete 1 Mega-Byte output of the command !!!

Comment: See updated question

Comment: The build information is missing. Provide the first ~50 lines of the console output, and provide the last ~50 lines of the console output.

Comment: With the command as specied above I get the output as given above. Again: I get EXACTLY the output as given above. There is NO build information. Again: There is no build information. I ONLY get the output as above! If you need other information please provide a way to get it!

Comment: Then I can only suggest to [download a recent `ffmpeg` build](http://ffmpeg.org/download.html#LinuxBuilds) and test with it.

Comment: In [this thread](http://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/828) at least the errors of "AC EOB marker is absent" was caused by the x264 that ffmpeg was using, which was fixed by installing gpac-devel-static (on fedora).

Comment: post the output of mplayer -identify filename.avi

Answer (score 7, accepted):

try using `mencoder` (the encoding part of `mplayer`) like this:

```
mencoder -idx problemfile.avi -ovc copy -oac copy -o reindexedfile.avi
```

(via http://www.kahunaburger.com/2010/01/30/fixing-an-avi-index-with-mencoder/)

Answer (score 2):

**Force index**

```
mencoder -forceidx input.avi -o output.avi -oac copy -ovc copy
```

**Copy all**

```
mencoder -ovc copy -oac copy input.file -o output.file
```

Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/894903/how-can-i-validate-a-video-file-from-a-script