# Repair broken avi file with known codec and frame size

Tags: video, ffmpeg, avi, mencoder

Is there a way to fix a broken avi (computer powered off during acquisition) if we know the frame size and the encoder? Opening in VLC and repairing it does not work. I have tried following some top answers from ([How can I repair a broken AVI file?](https://superuser.com/questions/4570/how-can-i-repair-a-broken-avi-file)). I have tried copying with ffmpeg, which gives the following error:

```
[avi @ 0x16aff60] Format avi detected only with low score of 1, misdetection possible!
```

mediainfo of Ok file:

```
Video
ID                                       : 0
Format                                   : JPEG
Codec ID                                 : MJPG
Duration                                 : 1h 29mn
Bit rate                                 : 51.0 Mbps
Width                                    : 4 704 pixels
Height                                   : 3 500 pixels
Display aspect ratio                     : 4:3
Frame rate                               : 3.000 fps
Color space                              : YUV
Chroma subsampling                       : 4:4:4
Bit depth                                : 8 bits
Compression mode                         : Lossy
Bits/(Pixel*Frame)                       : 1.033
Stream size                              : 32.1 GiB (100%)
```

mediainfo of broken file:

```
General
File size                                : 32.8 GiB
```